# C# streamwriter formatting issue

Tags: c#

I'd like to thank Stackoverflow member [Pratap .R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231511/pratap-r) first because he helped me with the code.  I'm still have a small formating issue with one of my replace functions.  What is happening is when I replace `</me>` it replaces with `;`.  I can't have the end of the row have a `;` at the end.

```
using (FileStream strm = new FileStream(exportfile, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strm))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            writer.Write((i == 0 ? "" : "|") + reader.GetName(i));

        writer.Write("\n");

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                writer.Write
                (
                    (i == 0 ? "" : "|") +
                    reader[i].ToString().Replace(@"<me> ","")
                        .Replace(@"</me>", "|").Replace(@"</me>", ";")
                        .Replace('\n', ' ').Replace('\r', ' ')
                );
            }

            writer.WriteLine();
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

So you can see when it occurs with  it's replaced with ";".  I can't have a ; end the row.  Any suggestions or tips always appricated.

Comment: Have you tried breaking it out into several lines and stepping through the code to see which Replace() is happening before it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` objects also have a wonderful `TrimEnd()` function

```
string s = "Hello;";
s = s.TrimEnd((char)';');
```

Comment: maybe a dumb question so forgive me, how would i apply this to what I have?

Comment: writer.Write((i==0?"":"|") + ((i==0?"":";") + reader[i].ToString().Replace(@"<swme> ", "").Replace(@"</swme>|", "|").Replace(@"</swme>", ";").Replace('\n', ' ').Replace('\r', ' ').TrimEnd((char)';')));

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to replace `</me>` with `;` , shouldn't you just remove this:

```
Replace(@"</me>", ";")
```

Comment: because i have to replace it with ;, <me> is multientry tag in SQL for a 3rd party program.  My line just cant end with ;.  So this exports a text file from SQL.

Comment: I was going to say that same thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you are doing so much on the one line?

Reading your code makes my head hurt!

```
string value = reader[i].ToString().Replace(@"<me> ", "").Replace(@"</me>|", "|").Replace(@"</me>", ";").Replace('\n', ' ').Replace('\r', ' ');

if (value.EndsWith(";"))
{
    value = value.Substring(0, value.Length - 1);
}
writer.Write((i == 0 ? "" : "|") + value);
```

Comment: ((i==0?"":"|") is the most important part of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could always change it to:

```
writer.Write((i==0?"":"|") + reader[i].ToString().Replace(@"<me> ", "").Replace(@"</me>|", "|").Replace(@"</me>", "; ").Replace('\n', ' ').Replace('\r', ' '));
```

Just add a space which is what you appear to do next